# Random walks and diffusive behaviour Python

Tags: python, random-walk

The signature of diffusive behaviour is that the average of the square of the distance of the walker from the origin after t steps is proportional to the number of steps.
Repeat the process for several walkers and step sizes (the text suggests 500 walkers and up to 100 steps), and plot a graph similar to the one in the textbook to confirm this.  Confirm also that the slope of such a graph is 1 as predicted.

I implemented the following code in Python and each time I run it the gradient I get is half the wanted value, and I could not find the mistake. Furthermore, this is the desired [graph](https://ibb.co/wMB48Gd), and my [graph](https://ibb.co/R7wR8sP). Can anyone spot what's wrong with the code?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nwalks=500
nsteps=100
x=np.zeros(nsteps)
x2avg=np.zeros(nsteps)

array=np.zeros((nwalks,nsteps))


for j in range(nwalks):
    x2=np.zeros(nsteps)  
    for i in range(1,nsteps):
        rnd=np.random.random()
        
        if rnd<0.5:
            x[i]=x[i-1]+1
        else:
            x[i]=x[i-1]-1
        
        x2[i]=x[i]**2
        x2avg[i]=(np.sum(x2))/(i+1)
        array[j,i]=x2avg[i]

y=np.mean(array, axis=0)      
i=np.arange(nsteps)
coeffs,cov=np.polyfit(i,y,1,cov=True)

grad=coeffs[0]
intercept=coeffs[1]
dgrad=np.sqrt(cov[0][0])
dintercept=np.sqrt(cov[1][1])
print(grad,dgrad)


f1=plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(i,y,color='black',marker='.')
#generating a function of the form y=mx + c
func = np.poly1d(coeffs)
# Getting the trendline(y values)
trendline = func(i)

plt.plot(i,trendline, 'k')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the impression that your line `x2avg[i]=(np.sum(x2))/(i+1)` is wrong. It calculates the mean squared distance over all steps in of the `i`th walker.

Just remove the `x2` and `x2avg` arrays and just use `array[j, i] = x[i]**2` in every inner loop:

```
for j in range(nwalks):
    x2=np.zeros(nsteps)
    for i in range(1,nsteps):
        rnd=np.random.random()

        if rnd<0.5:
            x[i]=x[i-1]+1
        else:
            x[i]=x[i-1]-1

        array[j,i]=x[i]**2
```

You do already calculate the mean in the very next line, which is the correct way:

```
y=np.mean(array, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this completely solved the issue!

Comment: A bit Offtopic, but it is much faster to perform a quadrature over a*a than over a**2.
0.35 ns vs 0.13 ns at my machine under py 3.6.7.